# jQuery mobile datebox: any API documentation?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox, daterangepicker

I am trying to use jquery.mobile datebox as a datepicker for my jquery mobile app...
I find some difficulties finding a page with the full APIs specification...
For example, I do not fully understand the option "useInlineHideInput", but I can't find any documentation about it...
Is there any jQuery mobile datebox API documentation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html) the full options list for the latest version jQM Datebox 2.

You can find information about the useInlineHideInput option [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/opt/dialog.html). It seems that this option is available in jQM Datebox 1. In version 2 you can force DateBox to display inline with 'useInline' and 'hideInput' set to 'true'.

To understand the functionality of the specific option put the following HTML in a file and change the options value from true to false.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page">
            <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
            <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"useInline": true, "useInlineHideInput": true}'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: fwiw, this is DateBox1 - which is somewhat superseded by [DateBox2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) - it isn't abandoned exactly, just probably won't see any updates. [API Docs](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html)